# does Azure Analysis Services have support for SystemAssigned Manged identity througth bicep template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity, azure-bicep, azure-analysis-services

I want to have a system assigned managed identity for azure analysis services thorough bicep template. is this supported?

when configuring bicep template tried to parse

```
identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
```

however getting the following warning

The property "identity" does not exist in the resource or type definition, although it might still be valid. If this is an inaccuracy in the documentation, please report it to the Bicep Team

the full bicep template can be seen below

```
resource ssas 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers@2017-08-01' = {
  name: 'as'
  location: loc
  sku: {
    name: 'name'
    tier: 'Basic'
    capacity: 1
  }
  properties: {
    ipV4FirewallSettings: {
      enablePowerBIService: true
      firewallRules: [
        {
          firewallRuleName: 'firewall'
          rangeEnd: 'my rangeEnd'
          rangeStart: 'my rangeStart'
        }
        {
          firewallRuleName: 'firewall'
          rangeEnd: 'rangeEnd'
          rangeStart: 'rangeStart'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
 
}
```

docs- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.analysisservices/servers?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Comment: have you tried to deployed? what's the issue here ?

Comment: @Thomas I deployed and the resources were created successfully however, managed identity was not configured . The docs don't mention anything about system assigned mi  for azure anlysis services. i want to understand if it is possible to use system mi with azure analysis services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-service-principal), it looks like it is not supported yet:

> Analysis Services does not support operations performed by managed identities using service principals. To learn more, see [Managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) and [Azure services that support Microsoft Entra authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-analysis-services).